# Pass database and PDO options arrays into my connection PHP file

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm learning some PHP while trying to build my own framework as apractice excersice, currently I have a config.php file where I store the database info to connect to plus some PDO settings, both stored into two different arrays.

I also have a Conectar.php file to stablish connection, in this the conexion(coection) method has to receive database and connection data from my arrays...

My ISSUE is I don't know if I a passing this info correctly and I also don't know how to pass my PDO settings array into the conection. Any help would be appreciated!

config.php

```html
<?php
$config = array(
    "driver"    =>"mysql",
    "host"      =>"localhost",
    "user"      =>"root",
    "pass"      =>"root",
    "dbname"  =>"projecto1",
    "charset"   =>"utf8"
 
);

PDOoptions = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
    PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING

);
?>
```

Conectar.php

```html
<?php
class Conectar{
    private $driver;
    private $host, $user, $pass, $database, $charset;
   
    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'config/database.php';
        $this->driver=$config["driver"];
        $this->host=$config["host"];
        $this->user=$config["user"];
        $this->pass=$config["pass"];
        $this->database=$config["database"];
        $this->charset=$config["charset"];
    }
 
 public function conexion(){
         
        if($this->driver=="mysql" || $this->driver==null)
  {
   try
   {
            $con= new PDO("mysql:host=$config['host'];dbname=$config['dbname']",$config['user'],$config['pass'],charset=$config['charset']);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
              echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
         
        return $con;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access to the `$config` variable which is not accessible in your `conexion()` function. Instead, you have to use the member's variable of your class, defined in your constructor :

```
$con = new PDO("{$this->driver}:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->database};charset={$this->charset}", 
               $this->user, $this->pass, $this->PDOoptions);
```

Also, in your configuration file, you're missing `$` in your `PDOoptions` variable. And store in your class :

```
private $PDOoptions ;
```

And in constructor :

```
$this->PDOoptions = $PDOoptions ;
```

So, the final code :

```
class Conectar{
    private $driver;
    private $host, $user, $pass, $database, $charset;
    private $PDOoptions ; // << NEW

    public function __construct() {
        require_once 'config/database.php';
        $this->driver=$config["driver"];
        $this->host=$config["host"];
        $this->user=$config["user"];
        $this->pass=$config["pass"];
        $this->database=$config["database"];
        $this->charset=$config["charset"];
        $this->PDOoptions=$PDOoptions; // << NEW
    }

    public function conexion(){
        $con = null ;
        if($this->driver=="mysql" || $this->driver==null)
        {
            try
            {
                // NEW // The 2 next lines are changed :
                $con = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->database};charset={$this->charset}", 
                       $this->user, $this->pass, $this->PDOoptions);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
              echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $con;
    }
}
```

Finally, the `$con` variable is undefined if the driver is not MySQL. So create a variable to `null` to avoid a notice.

Comment: @IncredibleHat yes, but I see the `require_once 'config/database.php';` in the constructor.

Comment: I need to clear my glasses ... ;) Cleaning up my comments yet again lol...

Comment: Mine too :p That's why I change my anwser so often! Thanks again @IncredibleHat !

Comment: How can I pass $PDOoptions to the pdo object ? also notice the require_once in the constructor

Comment: I don't know how to pass $PDOoptions into the con declaration, how would it look in my code?

Comment: @gabogabans Did you see the `// << NEW` comments, in the answer? Let me know if you don't understand what I said :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$con= new PDO("mysql:host={$config['host']};dbname={$config['dbname']}",$config['user'],$config['pass'],charset=$config['charset']);
```

You need curly braces in the quoted string.

Comment: why do  need curly braces for the host and dbname variables only?

Comment: @gabogabans In this case you have a **quoted string** who contains two variables: $config['host'] and $config['dbname']. You need to use curly braces in quotings when you **dereference arrays or objects**. The other arguments are passed as values directly as its own. Read here http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double and scroll to **variable parsing**.